# How to make Mysql variables work in a query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dynamic-columns

I've been struggling for a while now with attempting to generate code for automatic aggregations in my mysql/mariadb database. The method That i'm currently trying uses variables. I will admit in advance I'm not a database expert by any means. I'm totally self taught, and have been struggling to find adequate resources for this particular problem. Ive included simplified examples below, Oh and i'm using `mariadb 10.1`.

This code should work in `mysql 5.6` as well as `mariadb 10.0+`, I have tested it on 10.1 and it works.
Here is my Table: and [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09c418/3) <- doesn't work for some reason. Probably the dynamic columns. I'll leave it in case someone knows why.

```
CREATE TABLE data_points
(
  id          BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  device_id   INTEGER,
  dtime       DATETIME,
  sf          INTEGER(11), -- sample frequency or interval
  agg         INTEGER(11), -- aggregation type, actually a fk
  data_point BLOB,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (device_id, dtime, sf, agg)
);
```

Lets insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO data_points
    (device_id, dtime, sf, agg, data_point)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-01-02 12:00:00', 1, 60, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', 12, 'ab', 34, 'ac', 45)),
    (1, '2015-01-02 13:00:00', 1, 60, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', 12, 'ab', 34, 'ac', 45)),
    (1, '2015-01-02 14:00:00', 1, 60, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', 12, 'ab', 34, 'ac', 45)),
    (1, '2015-01-02 15:00:00', 1, 60, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', 12, 'ab', 34, 'ac', 45)),
    (1, '2015-01-02 16:00:00', 1, 60, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', 12, 'ab', 34, 'ac', 45));
```

So up to this point everything works just fine. What i'm trying to do is perform aggregations over different time periods, my lowest grain period is 60 seconds. Here is where I have issues, Its probably something obvious.

```
SELECT
  @dp_dtime := MAX(dtime),
  @dp_aa := MIN(ROUND(COLUMN_GET(data_point, 'aa' AS DOUBLE), 4)),
  @dp_ab := MIN(ROUND(COLUMN_GET(data_point, 'ab' AS DOUBLE), 4)),
  @dp_ac := MIN(ROUND(COLUMN_GET(data_point, 'ac' AS DOUBLE), 4))
FROM data_points
WHERE
  device_id = 1 AND
  dtime BETWEEN '2015/01/02 12:00:00' AND '2015/01/17 23:05:00' AND
  sf = 60 AND
  agg = 1;

INSERT INTO data_points
(device_id, dtime, sf, agg, data_point)
VALUES (8, @dp_dtime, 300, 2, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', @dp_aa, 'ab', @dp_ab, 'ac', @dp_ac));
```

This ends up creating another row with `NULL` everywhere a variable was in the statement.

```
select @dp_dtime, @dp_aa, @dp_ab, @pd_ac;
-- This results in NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

At this point I'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrong with the variables.
It's Late, 14 hour day. Am I even close? Is there a better/easier way?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
In my real use case the number of columns is dependent on the type of device were doing an aggregation for. Columns are excel style 'aa' through 'zz' possible. although the max I've seen is about 150 cols wide. This may sound like a bad design, but the performance is surprising, I can't tell the difference between these dynamic columns and actual columns. (at least as long as you don't need to index on them)

Comment: you want to create a dynamic query why not concat it as a string and use prepared statement to excute the query.

Comment: @RahulSingh I tried that at one point and couldn't get it to work, one issue is, in my real use-case, the amount of columns can be different for each device. anywhere between 'aa', and 'zz' (excel style columns). I'll look into prepared stmts again in the morning. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following queries.

## SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE data_points
(
  id          BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  device_id   INTEGER,
  dtime       DATETIME,
  sf          INTEGER(11), -- sample frequency or interval
  agg         INTEGER(11), -- aggregation type, actually a fk
  data_point BLOB,
  UNIQUE (device_id, dtime, sf, agg)
);
INSERT INTO data_points
    (device_id, dtime, sf, agg, data_point)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-01-02 12:00:00', 1, 1, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', 12, 'ab', 34, 'ac', 45)),
    (1, '2015-01-02 13:00:00', 1, 1, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', 12, 'ab', 34, 'ac', 45)),
    (1, '2015-01-02 14:00:00', 1, 1, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', 12, 'ab', 34, 'ac', 45)),
    (1, '2015-01-02 15:00:00', 1, 1, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', 12, 'ab', 34, 'ac', 45)),
    (1, '2015-01-02 16:00:00', 1, 1, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', 12, 'ab', 34, 'ac', 45));
select * from data_points;
SELECT
  @dp_dtime := MAX(dtime) as dp_dtime,
  @dp_aa := MIN(ROUND(COLUMN_GET(data_point, 'aa' AS DOUBLE), 4)) as dp_aa,
  @dp_ab := MIN(ROUND(COLUMN_GET(data_point, 'ab' AS DOUBLE), 4)) as dp_ab,
  @dp_ac := MIN(ROUND(COLUMN_GET(data_point, 'ac' AS DOUBLE), 4)) as dp_ac
FROM data_points
WHERE
  device_id = 1 AND
  dtime BETWEEN '2015/01/02 12:00:00' AND '2015/1/17 23:05:00' AND
  sf = 1 AND
  agg = 1;
INSERT INTO data_points
(device_id, dtime, sf, agg, data_point)
VALUES (8, @dp_dtime, 300, 2, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', @dp_aa, 'ab', @dp_ab, 'ac', @dp_ac));
select * from data_points;
```

## Output:

```
mysql> select * from data_points;
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+------+----------------------------+
| id | device_id | dtime               | sf   | agg  | data_point                 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+------+----------------------------+
|  1 |         1 | 2015-01-02 12:00:00 |    1 |    1 |            aaabacDZ |
|  2 |         1 | 2015-01-02 13:00:00 |    1 |    1 |            aaabacDZ |
|  3 |         1 | 2015-01-02 14:00:00 |    1 |    1 |            aaabacDZ |
|  4 |         1 | 2015-01-02 15:00:00 |    1 |    1 |            aaabacDZ |
|  5 |         1 | 2015-01-02 16:00:00 |    1 |    1 |            aaabacDZ |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+------+----------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   @dp_dtime := MAX(dtime) as dp_dtime,
    ->   @dp_aa := MIN(ROUND(COLUMN_GET(data_point, 'aa' AS DOUBLE), 4)) as dp_aa,
    ->   @dp_ab := MIN(ROUND(COLUMN_GET(data_point, 'ab' AS DOUBLE), 4)) as dp_ab,
    ->   @dp_ac := MIN(ROUND(COLUMN_GET(data_point, 'ac' AS DOUBLE), 4)) as dp_ac
    -> FROM data_points
    -> WHERE
    ->   device_id = 1 AND
    ->   dtime BETWEEN '2015/01/02 12:00:00' AND '2015/1/17 23:05:00' AND
    ->   sf = 1 AND
    ->   agg = 1;
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| dp_dtime            | dp_aa   | dp_ab   | dp_ac   |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2015-01-02 16:00:00 | 12.0000 | 34.0000 | 45.0000 |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO data_points
    -> (device_id, dtime, sf, agg, data_point)
    -> VALUES (8, @dp_dtime, 300, 2, COLUMN_CREATE('aa', @dp_aa, 'ab', @dp_ab, 'ac', @dp_ac));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from data_points;
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id | device_id | dtime               | sf   | agg  | data_point                                      |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |         1 | 2015-01-02 12:00:00 |    1 |    1 |            aaabacDZ                      |
|  2 |         1 | 2015-01-02 13:00:00 |    1 |    1 |            aaabacDZ                      |
|  3 |         1 | 2015-01-02 14:00:00 |    1 |    1 |            aaabacDZ                      |
|  4 |         1 | 2015-01-02 15:00:00 |    1 |    1 |            aaabacDZ                      |
|  5 |         1 | 2015-01-02 16:00:00 |    1 |    1 |            aaabacDZ                      |
|  6 |         8 | 2015-01-02 16:00:00 |  300 |    2 |       ▒  aaabac      (@      A@     ▒F@ |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why does this work, and not mine, (besides the few bugs I fixed in my question, like an sf of 60 that wasn't present in the table, is it just because you gave the columns names as well as assigned them to variables? Either way, this works, thank you for this.  I'll mark this as accepted

Comment: Well now i'm thoroughly befuddled, once I fixed the where conditions in the select statement, It worked just fine. Maybe I should stop working so late... nonetheless, your answer led me to my solution. Thanks.

Comment: In your original post, there are several bugs. After fixing them, it runs fine. `2015/00/17` was one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a simple typo:  I see `@_dtime`.

In the `UNIQUE` index, put `dtime` last; it will make the queries faster.  *Mini index lesson:* All `=` columns should come first in a composite index, in any order (cardinality makes virtually no difference).  Then you can put one 'range' (`dtime`).  Any columns after a range are not used for filtering.  See [my cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Get rid of `id` and promote the `UNIQUE` index to `PRIMARY KEY`; it will make the queries still faster.   *Mini index lesson:* Secondary keys (such as your `UNIQUE`) requires bouncing between the key and the data.  The `PRIMARY KEY` is clustered with the data (in InnoDB), thereby avoiding the bouncing.  Instead a 'range scan' over the PK is a range over the table.

Comment: Yeah, the typo was from copying and pasting the wrong code, all the variables used to start with _ instead of dp_. I thought Maybe it didn't like it that way, so i changed it. Still won't run with it fixed. The device_id filters out the most rows and  dtime key actually has the highest cardinality of all the keys, I was under the impression that for composite indexes this was the appropriate order for the most speed. Also this code all runs in a cluster, I thought the `Id` was mandatory as, node 1 uses 1,4,8, node 2 uses 2,5,9... Then again, the unique key kind of defeats the point of this.

Comment: Whoa -- What type of Cluster.  NDB? Galera? Other?  This _may_ be critical to the discussion.

Comment: I elaborated on the indexing issues.

Comment: Galera with rsync sst's

Comment: well you definitely understand indexes better than I do. This is good to know, I'll look at changing this, as I'm having too many issues with the cluster anyway, and I'm probably worrying about availability to far in advance anyway. So now i'm just running Mariadb 10.1.